# IPython 2.0 Notebook: where has the "Add Cell Above" button gone, and how do I get it back?

Tags: javascript, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I upgraded to IPython 2.0 today.

Alot of changes seem good, but the button to insert a new cell, above/below seems to be gone.
The option is still in the menu, and I believe the keyboard short cut works.
But the button is gone.

I'm sure there is a way to turn it back on, but the documentation for the new version doesn't seem super complete.
Possibly to turn it back on I need to adjust something in the config.
Which is just python script.
Maybe even tell it to insert a new element, and bind some javascript to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up teaching myself some javascript to do this.
You can make this change in the custom.js file.
which can be found in `~/.ipython/profile_[profile name]/static/custom`.

Replace it with the following:

```
$([IPython.events]).on('app_initialized.NotebookApp', function(){
             IPython.toolbar.add_buttons_group([
                 {
                      'label'   : 'Insert Cell Above',
                      'icon'    : 'fa-arrow-circle-o-up',
                      'callback': function () {
                                                    IPython.notebook.insert_cell_above('code');
                                                    IPython.notebook.select_prev();
                                                    IPython.notebook.focus_cell();
                      }
                 },
                 {
                      'label'   : 'Insert Cell Below',
                      'icon'    : 'fa-arrow-circle-o-down',
                      'callback': function () {
                                                    IPython.notebook.insert_cell_below('code');
                                                    IPython.notebook.select_next();
                                                    IPython.notebook.focus_cell();
                      }
                 }
                 ]);
             $('#insert_above_below').remove()
         });
```

If you have already modified it,
then you can not replace the whole file, obviously, and should merge the appropriate parts.

The buttons will show up on the right.
The single + button for below is also removed.

Answer (score 0):

These buttons relocated to "**Insert**" menu. However, it is always good idea to use shortcut commands:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> (split cell)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> (insert cell above)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> (insert cell below)

If you can master them and other basic commands, it will make your notebook workflow really slick. Full list of commands can be found [here](http://damontallen.github.io/IPython-quick-ref-sheets/).

Comment: I said that in my question post.
What I want to know is how i can get them back.
I am certain it can be done by edditing the .ipython/profive_nbserver/static/custom.js

Comment: We're glad to hear about keyboard shortcuts, but they're not substitutes for buttons. (And neither is a button a substitute for a keyboard shortcut.)

Answer (score 0):

as now in 5.7.4 version shortcut to create cell above is `esc` + `a`